# update panel for each row in grid view

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have an asp grid view which contains a text box and button.I have set a required field validator for the text box .But on clicking the button the required field validator doesn't shows up for the text box for the button i clicked(when the textbox is empty).Is there anyway to show the validator for text box based on the button i clicked?
also when i click on the button the command which is set for the button executes even when the text box is empty.
also i have place the item template in update panel so that the page does not refereshes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's much easier to help you if you show us what you have so far, and where you got stuck.

Comment: thank you for the concern. i have added the grid view with each row in update panel ,and i have taken the labels to show the data .
 like :this is one row
  date
  blog title
  teacher_name
  blog content
  add a comment(link button)
so when i click on link button a 
textbox appear,below the textbox there are two button
 comment(button 1)  cancel(button2)
 so when i click on the button 1 the comment goes to database.but if the there is no text in the text box required field validator doesn't appear , also there is hidden blog_id for every row,

Comment: Edit your question and add the extra information.

Comment: on click of a button in grid view the whole page refreshes,but i want that the when i click the button the page does not refreshes rather only the particular row refreshes and updates 
also the row should be updated....i have already use the update panel in **item template field** as well as for the **edit template field** but that does not work.please help me 
also how to update the specific row without being the whole page refreshed
thanx in advance

Comment: You use the [edit] link to change your question, and add the information there.

Comment: i have edited kindly see it please help me